# "Undefined variable: Profit $sum-$sub"

Tags: php

I am attempting to sum two arrays and subtract them from each other in PHP. Below is my attempt at it:

```
function total_price($totals)
{
  $sum = 0;
  $sub = 0;
  foreach ($totals as $total)
  {
    $sum += $total['total_selling_price'];
    $sub += $total['total_buying_price'];
    $profit = $sum - $sub;
```

}

What I'm trying to do is sum up everything in the sales array and subtract it by everything in the costs array (represented by variable $sub) in order to generate profit. However, I'm unable to, and I get the following error:

> UNDEFINED VARIABLE: PROFIT.

I've declared a profit variable within the `foreach`, so can someone tell me why my variable is considered undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign  `$profit = 0` out of loop.

Also validate totals before iterating.

```
if(is_array($totals)){
  foreach($totals as $total ){
    // write your code here
  }
}
```